# How to use pivot to generate weekly TimeTable

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2000, pivot

I want to generate weekly Timetable using sql server pivot.

my db have these tables.

```
        create table Students
        (
            StudentID int identity primary key,
            Name nvarchar(50)
        )
        create table Times
        (
            TimeID int identity primary key
            ,Name nvarchar(10)
        )
        create table Days
        (
            DayID int identity primary key 
            ,Name nvarchar(20)
        )
        create table TimeTable
        (
            StudentID int references Students(StudentID)
            ,TimeID int references Times(TimeID)
            ,DayID int references Days(DayID)
            ,Value nvarchar(50)
        )

        insert Times values('t1')
        insert Times values('t2')
        insert Times values('t3')



        insert Days values('sunday')
        insert Days values('monday')
        insert Days values('tuesday')
        insert Days values('wednesday')
        insert Days values('thursday')
        insert Days values('friday')
        insert Days values('saturday')
```

i want to have columns(DayID,DayName,t1,t2,t3)

i'm using this query but because of using Max(Value) aggregation function when i insert a record into TimeTable table this query show one value for columns t1,t2 and t3.however t2 and t3 should be null

```
            SELECT      *
            FROM         (SELECT     dbo.Days.DayID, dbo.Days.Name, dbo.Times.Name AS Expr1, dbo.TimeTable.Value
            FROM         dbo.Times CROSS JOIN
                                  dbo.Days LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                  dbo.TimeTable ON dbo.Days.DayID = dbo.TimeTable.DayID) AS d_1
            PIVOT (max (Value) FOR [Expr1] 
            IN (t1, t2, t3)) AS P
```

for example after execute these cmds, asp value showed for all columns.

```
        insert Students values('ahmad')
            insert TimeTable values(1,1,1,'asp')
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a match from TimeTable to Times:

```
 AND dbo.Times.TimeID = dbo.TimeTable.TimeID
```

Answer (score 0):

you were very close try this:

```
create table #Students
(
    StudentID int identity primary key,
    Name nvarchar(50)
)
create table #Times
(
    TimeID int identity primary key
    ,Name nvarchar(10)
)
create table #Days
(
    DayID int identity primary key 
    ,Name nvarchar(20)
)
create table #TimeTable
(
    StudentID int references #Students(StudentID)
    ,TimeID int references #Times(TimeID)
    ,DayID int references #Days(DayID)
    ,Value nvarchar(50)
)

insert #Times values('t1')
insert #Times values('t2')
insert #Times values('t3')

insert #Days values('sunday')
insert #Days values('monday')
insert #Days values('tuesday')
insert #Days values('wednesday')
insert #Days values('thursday')
insert #Days values('friday')
insert #Days values('saturday')

insert #Students values('ahmad')
insert #TimeTable values(1,1,1,'asp') 

SELECT *
FROM 
(
    SELECT     d.DayID, d.Name, t.Name AS Expr1, tt.Value
    FROM         #Times t 
    CROSS JOIN #Days d
    LEFT OUTER JOIN #TimeTable tt
        ON d.DayID = tt.DayID
        AND t.TimeID = tt.TimeID) AS d_1
PIVOT (max (Value) FOR [Expr1] 
IN (t1, t2, t3)) AS P 


drop table #Students
drop table #Times
drop table #Days
drop table #TimeTable
```

Comment: you are welcome, if the answer helped, then be sure that you mark it as the answer via the checkmark on the left.